# htaccess non-www rewrite showing index.php in URL

Tags: url, redirect, htaccess

I am using htaccess to rewrite any www url to a non-www version

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I type `domain.com/about` it works fine, however when I type `www.domain.com/about` it changes the URL to `domain.com/index.php?p=about`

I have `'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,` enabled.
I also have this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
Here is the the vhost file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Any of these help? https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php https://craftcms.com/support/why-index.php

Comment: @BradBell Thanks. I do have both of those in my .htaccess files and config already. I have edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official Apache documentation on Canonical domain rewrites: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

Comment: Thanks. I have had a look through these, none of the changes I have made has fixed the issue.
I am hosting the site on Digital Ocean, not sure if that affects anything in the vhost or htaccess setup

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question was the positioning of content in the .htaccess file.

Move:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Before this:

```
# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Although the L tag was in the previous statement, it should be the last rule applied, it doesn't work (probably because I was activating the RewriteEngine again later so it resets the rules, but if the L flag was active in the first rule, it wouldn't apply the www one anyway).

The rule of thumb is: first do your cosmetic changes to the domain, then apply the functional rules.